# RegEx - JavaScript - Validate a known domain with any protocol, subdomains and folders

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a known domain, like **domain.com** with JavaScript, but I need to validate it with any subdomain or sub-subdomains and so, and with any protocol and with any folder, sub-folder, and so, I have this regular expression:

```
RegEx: /http:\/\/([\.|a-z]+).domain([\.|a-z]+)\//
```

The problem is it not gets https/ftp/ftps... and it get *domain***.com**/*domain***.org**...
I need to validate, something like this:

```
To validate: *://*.domain.com/*
Example: http://example.domain.com/subfolder2/folder24/
Example: https://subdomain.domain.com/folder/
Example: ftp://www.example.domain.com/folder2/folder/
Example: http://www.domain.com/folder/sub-folder/
```

I mean, any protocol, any subdomain, and any folder, and of course, all of them together too:

```
Example: https://example.domain.com/folder/folder/
```

Any idea?

Comment: Ask google for "regex to validate domain names" and you will find plenty.

Comment: Do you understand the expression you are using?

Comment: @Mörre I did, and I get regular expressions for any domain, but I need for a particular domain...

Comment: @FelixKling I understand, it gets something like http://*.domain.*/* but I don't know how can I get what I need *://*.domain.com/*

Comment: For starters, replace `domain([\.|a-z]+)` with `domain\.com`. `http` of course does not match `https` or `ftp` or the like. But you can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to allow more protocols.

Comment: I did, and it not validates folders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/[.a-z]+\.domain\.com[.a-z0-9/-]+/
```

This will match the domains you lisited:

```
http://example.domain.com/subfolder2/folder24/
https://subdomain.domain.com/folder/
ftp://www.example.domain.com/folder2/folder/
http://www.domain.com/folder/sub-folder/
```

How it works:

```
# /            - Regex start,
# ^            - Match the start of the string,
# (https?|ftp) - followed by `https`, `http` or `ftp`,
# :\/\/        - followed by `://`,
# [.a-z]+      - followed by any amount of letters or periods,
# \.           - followed by a period,
# domain\.com  - followed by the domain name,
# [.a-z0-9/-]+ - followed by the rest of a possible url.
# /            - regex end.
```

Comment: It validates too domain.org, I need ony domain.com with or without subdomains/folders...

Comment: @David: Just replace `domain[.a-z0-9/-]+` with `domain\.com`

Comment: @Cerbrus: You should use `^` to anchor the regex.

Comment: If we don't care about the path, `/^(https?|ftp):\/\/[.a-z]+\.domain\.com(?:\/|$)/`. If we care about the path, `/^(https?|ftp):\/\/[.a-z]+\.domain\.com(?:\/[.a-z0-9/-]*|$)/`. I think `[.a-z0-9/-]` fail to cover quite a lot of cases, though.

Comment: `[.a-z]` and `[.a-z0-9/-]` could be shortened to `\w+` and `[\w/-]+`.

Comment: @Simon: nope, you're forgetting the `.` in my regex.